# Express middlware not called on sub paths

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an API backend with Express (v4) and facing an issue that my middleware function is not called
on sub-paths of my route. E.g. it is called for */movie* but not for */movie/search*.

I have split my routes into separate files. Below is the code, shortened to the relevant parts.

Any help is appreciated!

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = require('routes')(app);
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/movie', check_authentication, require('movie'));
};
```

**/routes/movie.js**

```
var Movie = require(../models/movie');

// Middleware is working for this route (/movie?movie_id=123)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    Movie.findById(req.query.movie_id)
        .then(function(movie) {
            res.status(200).json(movie);
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
});

// Middleware is NOT working for this route (/movie/search?keyword=matrix)
router.get('/search', function(req, res) {

    Movie.findById(req.query.keyword)
        .then(function(movie) {
            res.status(200).json(movie);
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
    });
```

**/routes/check_authentication.js**

```
var express         = require('express');
var router          = express.Router();
var firebaseAdmin   = require('firebase-admin');
var path            = require('path');
var config          = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../config/config.json'));

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({   
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(path.resolve(__dirname,   '../config/' + config.firebase.serviceAccount)), 
    databaseURL: config.firebase.databaseURL
});

// AUTHENTICATION MIDDLEWARE
// needs to be included in any request which requires authorization
// =============================================================================
router.all('/', function(req, res, next) {

    // check if authorization header is present
    var token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (typeof token === 'undefined') {
        res.status(403).json({ Error: 'Unauthenticated' });
    }
    else {
        firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(function(decodedToken) {
            req.email = decodedToken.email;
            next(); // all good. go ahead with the request
        }).catch(function(error) {
            res.status(403).json({ Error: 'Unauthenticated' });
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check_authentication module should export the middleware function, not a router.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    // check if authorization header is present
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Great! That's much cleaner than using the wildcard option.

Answer (score 3):

It seems I found the problem.
Changing the middleware to trigger on * fixes it.

```
router.all('*', function(req, res, next)
```

Maybe someone can confirm that this is the way to go.

Comment: It will work this way but, no, it is unfortunately not the right way. Check the answer of @djones. You should not declare your check_authentication as a router. For such things, you should use a middleware. Don't export a router, instead just export a function with req, res and next as parameters. The code inside the function will be the same as it is in your router.